# Print external page without open it

Tags: javascript, php, browser, printing

I want print a page without open it on all major browsers. (Safari, IE, firefox, Chrome and Opera)

I tried that but doesn't work on firefox (Error : Permission denied to access property 'print') :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Test</title>
            <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
            <link rel="alternate" media="print" href="print.php"> 
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function impression() {
                window.frames[0].focus();
                window.frames[0].print();
                }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>


            <iframe height="0px" src="print.php" id="fileToPrint" style="visibility: hidden"></iframe>
            <a href="javascript:impression()">Imprimer</a>
        </body>
    </html>
```

This code works on Chrome.

I want one thing like that for all browsers to mention but I don't know how.

Is there another way to do that?

Comment: that can help you --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165821/print-a-pdf-iframe-in-firefox

Comment: There's no cross browser solution for this, in some browsers it will work with an iFrame, in others you might need a new window, and if I remember correctly none of the above worked in one of the five browsers.

Comment: Try replacing `window.frames[0]` with `document.getElementById('fileToPrint').contentWindow` and see if that works in firefox.

Comment: Why you are not using a framework to do this?, jQuery for instance!

Comment: @Ma'moonAl-Akash - How does jQuery help with printing ?

Comment: @adeneo : I tried but it give me the same error.

Comment: They both seem to work for me in Firefox, so I have no idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an iframe, hide it, and then call the proper print functions. The execCommand should work for all versions of IE.
Mind you: $.browser won't work for newer versions of jQuery and should be avoided. Use your preferred way of detecting features.

```
var ifr = createIframe();
ifr.hide();

if ($.browser.msie) {
    ifr.contentWindow.document.execCommand('print', false, null);
} else {
    ifr.contentWindow.focus();
    ifr.contentWindow.print();
}
```

This was developed for IE, FF and Chrome. I have no idea how well this will work for Safari and Opera, but it might give you some ideas.

Edit: as adeneo correctly pointed out, $.browser is deprecated and should be avoided. I updated my statement. I'll leave my code untouched, as it still expresses the correct intent.

Comment: It's not "iffy", `$.browser` is deprecated and removed from jQuery

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code, but it's Javascript ;

```
<script language="JavaScript">
var gAutoPrint = true; // Tells whether to automatically call the print function

function printSpecial()
{ 
if (document.getElementById != null)
{
var html = '<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n';

if (document.getElementsByTagName != null)
{
var headTags = document.getElementsByTagName("head");
if (headTags.length > 0)
html += headTags[0].innerHTML;
}

html += '\n</HE>\n<BODY>\n';

var printReadyElem = document.getElementById("printReady");

if (printReadyElem != null)
{
html += printReadyElem.innerHTML;
}
else
{
alert("Could not find the printReady function");
return;
}

html += '\n</BO>\n</HT>';

var printWin = window.open("","printSpecial");
printWin.document.open();
printWin.document.write(html);
printWin.document.close();
if (gAutoPrint)
printWin.print();
}
else
{
alert("The print ready feature is only available if you are using an browser. Please update your browswer.");
}
}

</script>
```